# Perl PostgreSQL queries executes twice

Tags: postgresql, perl, plpgsql

I was trying to understand why it is happening but I could not find it. SQL Queries executes twice.

piece of my script:

```
my $driver = "Pg"; # Driver Name
my $database = $ARGV[0]; # First argument will be database name
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database;host=127.0.0.1;port=5432";
my $userid = $ARGV[1]; # second argument will be username
my $password = $ARGV[2]; # third argument will be passwd
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$userid,$password,  {RaiseError => 1 }) or die $DBI::errstr;

sub f_createUser {
    if (scalar @_ != 3 ) {
        return;
    }
    my $query = $dbh->prepare(qq{ SELECT createUserWithPassword(?,?) });
    #my $result = $dbh->do($query) < 0 ? say "$DBI::errstr" : "# >>> Query worked successfully";
    $query->execute($_[1],$_[2]);
}

&f_createUser(@revelantArray);
```

When I execute script, I got:

> DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  role "tesstt" already exists
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE USER tesstt WITH PASSWORD '123'"
>   PL/pgSQL function createuserwithpassword(character varying,character
>   varying) line 3 at EXECUTE statement at homework2.pl line 39, 
>   line 1. DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  role "tesstt" already
>   exists CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE USER tesstt WITH PASSWORD
>   '123'" PL/pgSQL function createuserwithpassword(character
>   varying,character varying) line 3 at EXECUTE statement at homework2.pl
>   line 39,  line 1.

Why is this happening ? What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `PrintError => 1`, which prints an error message on error.

You have `RaiseError => 1`, which throws an exception consisting of an error message. Uncaught exceptions are printed as they end the program.

Add `PrintError => 0` to the options passed to `DBI->connect`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, do I have PrintError => 1 ? where do I have it ? Where am I supposed to add PrintError => 0, could you specify bit more ?

Comment: It's one of the `connect`'s options. That's the default.

Comment: allrigth but how should I add to PrintError => 0 ? where am I supposed to that ?

Comment: Add it to `connect`'s options.